# QTreeView, QItemDelegate & refresh other item?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have a `QTreeView` and the `QItemDelegate` of it.
And the `QTreeView` has many many items.

The Goal:

If I select one of these items, then not only the selected item but also some other(after my other conditions) items must be repainted(for example, other color) too.

The Problem :

If I select one item in `QTreeView`, then the selected item and the other items are internally repainted through my `QItemDelegate`. So far is good.
But the change of these other items is not visible until i select other windows and select this `QTreeView` again.

So.. I have tested the following functions..

> repaint(), update(), etc...

But it does not make any change.

Only if I select any other windows and selcect the `QTreeView` widget again, then I can see the changes..

How can I refresh the `QTreeView` and make the changes by `QItemDelegate` visible?

Comment: Maybe it works by emitting dataChanged for those items?

Comment: Try to read Qt documentation and provide and SSCCE, that describes your problem.

Comment: @fassl because of many items and the very time consuming effect caused by dataChanged() signal, i should not use emitting dataChanged() signal..

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it in my QTreeWidget subclass is this:

```
void MyTreeWidgetSubclass :: ForceUpdateItem(QTreeWidgetItem * li)
{
   int lastIndex = columnCount()-1;
   QRect firstColCellRect = visualRect(indexFromItem(li, _headerView->logicalIndex(0)));
   QRect lastColCellRect = visualRect(indexFromItem(li, _headerView->logicalIndex(lastIndex))));
   viewport()->update(firstColCellRect | lastColCellRect);
}
```

Obviously if you are using the QTreeView class directly instead of the QTreeWidget subclass, you'll need to modify that a bit, but the principle is the same:  the QTreeView class still has the visualRect() method to give you the on-screen location of a given QModelIndex, so you can use that to calculate the QRect representing the visual location of the index or indices you want updated, and then call viewport()->update() with that QRect as the argument.

Comment: well... i have tested it, but it does not solve the problem in my case.. maybe because i'm using QT 4.8.6 ??